# Detect and Prevent User Routing To A Domain Outside The Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url-routing, angular-routing

I have an angular app and on one component, I want to detect routing outside of the angular app domain.

For Example: The user is on the upload component where important information is being processed and the user navigates out the app through router, window.location.href, window.location.assign, manually entering a url, clicking a url on an ad. I want to detect that event in angular and depending on a condition, either performing the route or preventing it.

I know there is a way through router which detects route changes but it doesnt work with window.location routing or when clicked a link in an ad popup. The following is the router approach I tried but it didnt work:

```
this.router.events.forEach((e: any) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log('routing to ' + JSON.stringify(e));
      }
    });
```

Basically, I want to prevent all external routing on one component of the app while maintaining routing to app routes. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the `canDeactivate` guard ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will canDeactive manage routing through url’s in ads or iframes? Arnt AuthGuards just for angular routes and internal routing and wont work when routing to external sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event i.e. **beforeunload** with the **HostListener** as mentioned below.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-upload',
 templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})
export class UploadComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // Subscribe to Angular Router events
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any): void {
    // You can add custom logic here to prompt the user before leaving the page
    // For example, return a confirmation message
    $event.returnValue = true;
  }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

**Updated code if you do not need any popups**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload',
  templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Check if the new URL is within your app's domain
        const isInternalRoute = event.url.startsWith('/your-app-root');

        if (!isInternalRoute) {
          // External navigation detected, prevent it
          console.warn('External navigation prevented.');
          // Optionally, you can redirect to a specific route within your app
          this.router.navigate(['/']); // Redirect to home or another route
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yes, this works but the issue is i do not want a popup. I simply wanna check if the app is routing within the app, then proceed otherwise if its an external link or ad url, it ignores it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes @z123, it is possible. you can check the update code.